# Performance Effect of multiple attributes in session?

Tags: java, http, session

What are the possible performance effect of keeping heavy objects(like hashMaps) or many light objects(like short strings or Integers) in httpSession particularly for java platform containers?
I feel like i should use session as less as possible but i am not very clear on that.
How is session maintained?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in the session scope uses RAM as well as objects in the request scope. But data in the request scope is deleted after work is done. What happens to the session data depends on your container and configuration. The session data could be serialized to disk to free some RAM. Serialization and deserialization need time and cose some disk space. When your app runs on several nodes, the session data is replicated between all nodes. This costs network bandwith between the nodes and of cause time.

Answer (score 0):

If request attribute is fullfill your requirement then don't use session attribute. For that first of all you have to decide which attribute will be used in reqest and which will be used for entire session.

Comment: obviously performance degrade as memory occupied for entire session. It's also depend on session timeout period.